# How to check weblogic version using wlst

Tags: weblogic, wlst

I want to conditionally execute some wlst commands based the the weblogic version. How to get the weblogic version using wlst?

Comment: Does it help - http://onlineappsdba.com/index.php/2011/04/28/how-to-find-oracle-weblogic-server-version/

Answer (score 2):

The `version` command is supported by wlst.
Below is the output of version command executed with wlst (version 12.2.1)

> wls:/offline> print version
>
> `WebLogic Server 12.2.1.2.0`

With wlst script you can check the version and perform the version specific commands. For example, create a script called `test.py` as below

```
weblogic_version=version

if 'WebLogic Server 12.2.1' in weblogic_version:
    print "Perform commands for weblogic version 12.2.1"
else:
    print "You are on required weblogic version"
```

You can now execute this script with `wlst.sh`

```
.../wlst.sh test.py
```

Ref:https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLSTC/reference.htm#WLSTC516

Comment: Is there a command to see java version and JDK/JRE Path used by WebLogic servers?