# Find the WebLogic version using Python

Tags: python, weblogic

How can I find the WebLogic version of a Linux system using Python code?

Note - I tried exploring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46968449/how-to-check-weblogic-version-using-wlst) link but not found much information about it.

Comment: Does [this](https://onlineappsdba.com/index.php/2011/04/28/how-to-find-oracle-weblogic-server-version/) help?

Comment: @helloworld , yes this helps! Thank you! I could see the provided link has the Linux commands to fetch the WebLogic version. If in case you have any idea on how I can implement these commands in Python code, could you kindly suggest me please?

Comment: Try using the os and subprocess modules in python